# Can't download web page content

Tags: java, android-asynctask, httpsurlconnection

I am new to java and android, and as part of a course I am doing, I have to download the contents of a web page to the Log. Howver I can't get it to work. I'm getting the errors:
 Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
NullPointerException

I'm using Android Studio 3.5

Thank you.

I've tried checkiong the code against the course code and it matches.

```
    package com.android.guessthecelebrity;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public class downloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String result = "";
        URL url;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

        try {
            url = new URL(urls[0]);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);
            int data  = reader.read();

            while (data != -1) {

                char current = (char)data;
                result += current;
                data= reader.read();
            }

        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        downloadTask task = new downloadTask();
        String result = null;
        try {
            result = task.execute("http://www.posh24.se/kandisar").get();

            String [] splitResult = result.split("<div class=\"sidebarContainer\">");
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);// [0] refers to the part before the split point

            while (m.find()) {
                System.out.println(m.group(1));

            }

            p = Pattern.compile("alt=\"(.*?)\"");
            m = p.matcher(splitResult[0]);// [0] refers to the part before the split point


            System.out.println(m.group(1));

        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

I expect the web page content to be returned to the Log

Comment: Tell us how have you debugged it and what have you observed during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Okay Oliver, let me help you out before you get trolled as you are new here,

**Welcome to StackOverflow :)**

There is not much of the error log in Question, However the error does tell you that one of the object is not initialized due to which you get `NullPointerException` (welcome to the most seen error in java).

I have put together some code which works to help you out here.

Few things to Note,

- make sure that your activity is present in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
- this is `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` present in you AndroidManifest.xml file.

  ```
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

  import java.io.BufferedReader;
  import java.io.IOException;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.io.InputStreamReader;
  import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
  import java.net.MalformedURLException;
  import java.net.URL;
  import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

  import your.package.name.R;


  public class GetWebContentActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



  private static final String TAG = "GetWebContent";

  private TextView webContentTextView;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_web_content);
      setSupportActionBar(findViewById(R.id.toolbar));
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

      webContentTextView = findViewById(R.id.web_content_text_view);
      (new GetWebContent()).execute("https://www.google.com/"); //argument is the website link

  }

  class GetWebContent extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

      private String webContentResult = "Couldn't get web content";

      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

          String urlOfTheWebsite = strings[0];

          try {
              URL url = new URL(urlOfTheWebsite);

              HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

              InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();

              BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

              String tempText = null;
              StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
              while ((tempText = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                  stringBuilder.append(tempText);
              }

              webContentResult = stringBuilder.toString();
          } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return webContentResult;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
          super.onPostExecute(s);

          Log.d(TAG, "" + s); // you may log the web content like this
          //or
          webContentTextView.setText("" + s); // print this on UI
      }

  }
  }
  ```

[image]

- Please try to check every error you get on Google (StackOverflow)
- try to consider a tight feedback loop to your coding, as you get them you would  pick up any mistakes as quickly as possible.
- If you are new to java consider few tutorials ([Practical Programming](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCo7riiccNWJ29oAHLHaHY4A/featured)).
- Java is a Typed language and good place to start if you are learning programming, However if you want to stick with Android consider moving to Kotlin language
- Do little homework before asking a question, it would be rewarding in Stack-overflow,
- Please help others when you can.